# Advanced calculus integral

Tags: calculus, integration

How do you integrate the following?

$$\int_0^1 \! \frac{(x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}  \, \mathrm{d}y.$$

and

$$\int_0^1 \! \frac{(x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}  \, \mathrm{d}x.$$

Comment: What did you try so far? :)

Comment: *At the end of the day, $x^2$ is just a (non-negative) number...*

Comment: Note that the results will be opposite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $y=x\tan \theta.$

Then $$\int \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}dy =\frac{1}{x}\int
\cos (2 \theta)d\theta =\frac{1}{2x}\sin(2 \theta)=\frac{1}{x}\frac{\tan \theta}{1+\tan^2 \theta}=\frac{y}{x^2+y^2} .$$

So
$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}dy =\frac{y}{x^2+y^2} |_0^1= \frac{1}{x^2+1}.$$

Comment: Oh, i forgot the $x$ ill have to change the limits, thanks.

Comment: Now in the second to last step of finding the indefinite integral (changing from sin(2_theta) to tangents), is there a systematic way to turn sines into tangents, or was this a result of keen obeservation?